# PHP strtotime gives me a hour to much

Tags: javascript, php

I have a datetime in a database table, let's say '2014-08-05 15:12:00'
I use this date with strtotime() and convert this to miliseconds. Then on the clientside
I use
    var date = new Date(date_in_miliseconds)

But the generated date's hour is 1 hour in plus. It is not 15:12, but is 16:12

How can I solve this?

Comment: What timezone are you in? What timezone is your server in? Are you on daylight saving time?

Comment: timezone of server is Europe\Berlin and my time zone is Eastern European Time Zone (UTC+02:00)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the PHP script on the server uses the correct timezone to convert the time to milliseconds. You can use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the base timezone.